# Dialog jquery not resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have dialog in Jquery

The dialog is opens ok, and after it's open I set the height and width.

The height changes but the width does not

WHY?!

thanks
Omer
Israel

Comment: Your question makes little sense.

Comment: could you please show us some of your jquery/javascript code? this way we can't help you

Comment: Please post the relevant jQuery code. It's impossible to help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

set this option:

```
resizable: false,
```